# Android Room: select list of custom objects removing duplicates by a specific property

Tags: android, android-room

I'm using Room library to retrive a List without duplicates for property "text".
This is the code of the query in MyObjectDao class:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM historyentity WHERE text LIKE :inputText || '%'")
List<MyObject> findByText(String inputText);
```

I also post MyObject class:

```
@Entity
public class MyObject {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
public int uid;

@ColumnInfo(name = "text")
public String text;

@ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp")
public Long timestamp;
```

}

Anyway I still get get results with duplicates for field "text". How can I get a List that does not contains duplicates on field "text"?

For example if I have the following three elements in the database

```
database.addMyObject(new MyObject("dog", System.currentTimeInMills());
database.addMyObject(new MyObject("cat", System.currentTimeInMills());
database.addMyObject(new MyObject("dog", System.currentTimeInMills());
```

when I call my query I want to get only the first two elements.

Comment: what is the `|| '%'` supposed to do? it's a wildcard, and I think that's what messes the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just list with unique `text` values you can try this one:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT text FROM historyentity WHERE text LIKE :inputText || '%'")
List<String> findByText(String inputText); // <-- changed type to List<String>
```

**UPDATE**

You can try this query (it gets only one item with `text` value - with maximal `id` - or you can use maximal (or minimal) `timestamp`):

```
Select * from historyentity as t1
    INNER JOIN (select text,max(uid) as uid from historyentity WHERE text LIKE :inputText group by text) t2
    ON t1.text = t2.text and t1.uid = t2.uid
```

Comment: I want to have a List<MyObject> instead of List<String>. But in the list I don't want to have elements with the same "text" field.

Comment: So if there are several items with the same `text` field you expect to get any of them (but only one of them)? At first sight it seems strange. Can you put some example in your post for clarity?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question adding an example, thanks.